# drop nan in a subset of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe

df with `columns=['ID','Region','Day 1','Day 2','Day 3','Day 4','Day 5']`

how can I drop the rows containing NaN in the columns `'Day 1','Day 2','Day 3','Day 4','Day 5'` ?

I would like to use something "from day 1 to day 5"

```
df.dropna(axis=0, how='all', thresh=None, subset=['Day 1':'Day 5'], inplace=True)
```

but the above code doesn't seem to work

Comment: The NaN values must be in all columns, or any of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to repeat all columns, e.g. by:

```
c = ['Day {}'.format(x) for x in range(1 , 6)]
print (c)
['Day 1', 'Day 2', 'Day 3', 'Day 4', 'Day 5']
```

Or:

```
c = df.loc[:, 'Day 1':'Day 5'].columns
```

---

```
df.dropna(axis=0, how='all', thresh=None, subset=c, inplace=True)
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':list('abcdef'),
                   'Region':[np.nan,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'Day 1':[7,8,9,4,2,np.nan],
                   'Day 2':[1,3,5,7,1,np.nan],
                   'Day 3':[np.nan] * 6,
                   'Day 4':[5,3,6,9,2,np.nan],
                   'Day 5':[5,3,6,9,2,np.nan]})

print (df)
   Day 1  Day 2  Day 3  Day 4  Day 5 ID  Region
0    7.0    1.0    NaN    5.0    5.0  a     NaN
1    8.0    3.0    NaN    3.0    3.0  b     5.0
2    9.0    5.0    NaN    6.0    6.0  c     4.0
3    4.0    7.0    NaN    9.0    9.0  d     5.0
4    2.0    1.0    NaN    2.0    2.0  e     5.0
5    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  f     4.0

c = df.loc[:, 'Day 1':'Day 5'].columns
df.dropna(axis=0, how='all', thresh=None, subset=c, inplace=True)
print (df)
   Day 1  Day 2  Day 3  Day 4  Day 5 ID  Region
0    7.0    1.0    NaN    5.0    5.0  a     NaN
1    8.0    3.0    NaN    3.0    3.0  b     5.0
2    9.0    5.0    NaN    6.0    6.0  c     4.0
3    4.0    7.0    NaN    9.0    9.0  d     5.0
4    2.0    1.0    NaN    2.0    2.0  e     5.0
```